# Mobile Broadband connection server

Tags: python, network-programming, server

I'm using a mobile broadband connection and I was trying to create a simple server to send and receive messages using python. Is there a way to create a server with this connection?
PS. The internal and external IP addresses are different.

Comment: do you have access to the computer via the IP address provided by the connection?

Comment: You have to first answer whether mobile broadband provider support this, and whether your devices (i.e. mobile broadband router/modem) will let your server listen. This is not any different than any other protocol/languages that sit on top of the hardware layer. [This may be a problem for you](https://serverfault.com/questions/337943/mapping-a-private-server-running-in-3g-mobile-network-to-a-public-subdomain/337953#337953) or alternatively try asking on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com).